# Is there any hidden significance to the song at the end o S06E09?

Tags: analysis, soundtrack, castle

Just before the credits at the end of *Castle* S06E09 there is this scene:

The look on Becketts face made me think it could have an underlying meaning other than 3XKs return anyway.

Comment: All I can think of is that it's called "We'll Meet Again," implying that he's still around.

Comment: @Tom seems like the answer is probably just 'no' then :)

Comment: Maybe he also planned to [nuke the planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Strangelove)? ;)

Answer (score 1):

As Tom has said, it meant that either:

1. 3XK is around.
2. It was speculated that the song had a profound meaning to Beckett (related to her marriage / mother) that 3XK knew about.

Unfortunately we never got around to explore these two cases.